# Converting hex 64 to decimal in js

Tags: contract-development, tokens, balances

I am getting totalSupply of Tokens of a contract using ERC20 totalsupply method.

I am trying to convert hex returned to decimal.

I am receiving:

```
var totalSupply = "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c6b935b8bbd400000";
```

Then I am doing:

```
console.log(parseInt(totalSupply, 16))
```

But I get a scientific number, how can I show regular number? am I converting it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're parsing the number correctly. Your question is really "How do I convert a number in JavaScript to a string without scientific notation?"

The BigNumber library does a good job of this, and it's included in `web3.js`:

```
> var totalSupply = '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c6b935b8bbd400000';
undefined
> web3.toBigNumber(totalSupply).toFixed()
"2000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: send me your paypal, I will send you a beer!!! you are always helping me, thanks buddy!

Comment: thanks. btw, is there a handful tool to do it on-the-go, without console and web3?

Answer (score 1):

Web3 keeps changing. Today it can be done with:

```
parseInt(web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter("uint256", totalSupply)) / 10 ** 18
```

eval works too and won't ever change:

```
eval("0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c6b935b8bbd400000") / 10 ** 18
```